# CSS change height of element hardware accellerated on ipad

Tags: ipad, css, safari, hardware-acceleration, reflow

Working on a HTML5 app for iPad I would like to change the height of an element hardware accellerated.

I have created a viewport (parent, overflow:hidden) on a child-element (absolutly positioned, larger than parent), extending the height of the viewport should reveal a larger part of the child element.

The animation looks really nice on my desktop browser (Chrome), but when running on my iPad (iOS 6) the animation is not so smooth.

The following JSFiddle illustrates the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/schade/bqsnS/ (use iPad to see the problem and Chrome to see how it should work)

Ive debugged the iPad and my conclusion is that it does a lot of reflowing and, for now, my conclusion is that chaigning height of a parent element always forces redraw of child elements on the iPad, no matter how i set the position of the child elements. Or?

Does anyone has a fix for this?

Or some kind of nice workaround?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you can force hardware acceleration on an element in CSS3 on iOS by applying the following style:

```
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

Hope this helps